# How to call another service/api only if the first one has successfully executed?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

I am very new to angular and typescript. I have been trying this.

```
doSomething() {
    return this.http.post(this.path + "dosomething", data).toPromise();
}
```

now in .ts you are awaiting it

```
await servicesCalls.doSomething();
```

Upon its success implementation I need to do the same with all another maps from service.

But first I want to make sure it has posted the data.

```
await serviceCalls.doAnotherThing();
```

The `api` is returning `IHTTPACTIONRESULT` i.e. `Ok()`.

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply store this in a variable like this,

`const promise = servicesCalls.doSomething();`

and simply call the next one like this,

`promise.then(async () => await serviceCalls.doAnotherThing()).catch(e => console.error(e));`

The next API call will only be executed when the previous promise resolves.

Comment: that's a pointer in the right direction, but an awaited promise is no promise anymore. you are mixing async/await and then-blocks. your "promise" variable already contains the response. so either remove the "await" or use "await" all the way.

Comment: @MarkusDresch Yes, you're right! Edited the answer.

Comment: may I ask if there's any performance implication as to using Promises vs subscribing? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use promises.
HTTP methods in Angular return an Observable. You can subscribe to that observable, an when that observable emits some data then in the subscribe method you can call another service.

Something like this::

```
doSomething() {
    return this.http.post(this.path + "dosomething", data);
}
```

Now there are various different ways to do this:

**Method one**: Normal way. Call another service in the subscription of the first one.

Component:

```
public callService() {
    doSomething.subscribe(data => {
        serviceCalls.doAnotherThing();
    },
    err => {
        // do something
    })
}
```

Subscription will only be called when doSomething function( that is your HTTP request returns some value).

**Method 2**: You can use rxjs operators - switchMap like this:

```
doSomething()
    .pipe(
        //Use switchMap to call another API(s)
        switchMap((dataFromServiceOne) => {
            serviceCalls.doAnotherThing();
        })
    ).subscribe((data) => {
        // do something with response
        console.log(data);
    });
```

For more details about rxjs operators:

1. [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)
2. [Observables](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)

Answer (score 2):

Use switchMap

```
doSomething() {
    return this.http.post(this.path + "dosomething", data);
}


doAnotherthing() {
    return this.http.post(this.path + "dosomething", data);
}

doSomething().pipe(
  tap(doSomethingResponse => this.performSomeOperation(doSomethingResponse)),
  switchMap(_ => this.doAnotherthing())
).subscribe(doAnotherthingResponse => console. log(doAnotherthingResponse));
```

Answer (score 0):

when using angular http client, you'd typically subscribe to the observable as mentioned in [@Drashti Dobariya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278730/9423721). when using `async`/`await`, you might as well just use `fetch`.

when `await`ing something, the program flow continues after the awaited promise resolved. what you probably want is a check, if the http request succeeded:

```js
let response = await servicesCalls.doSomething();

// you may have to handle different status codes
if (response.status != 200) {
  return;
}

response = await serviceCalls.doAnotherThing();
```